# How is Pokérus handled in championship?

Tags: pokemon-series

I was thinking, is Pokérus negated or banned at all for the Pokémon video game championships? Because if not, I would think it would be absolutely necessary for any level of competition in the tournaments.

I looked through the [posted championship rules](http://gamesites.nintendo.com.au/pokemon-video-game-championships/rules.php) and I couldn't find any reference to Pokérus, and on [Serebii's](http://www.serebii.net/games/pokerus.shtml) entry for Pokérus there is no mention of championship at all, so is there any ruling about this?

Comment: What do you think Pokerus does? It helps with EV training but not during an actual fight

Comment: @Angzuril Don't EVs help with the gaining of base stats (HP, Attack, Defense, Sp. Attack, Sp. Defense, Speed) which would boost the overall capabilities of a Pokemon?

Comment: I've tried to update my answer to address your comment

Comment: @Angzuril So they increase how fast your EVs go up, but they don't change EV cap so it wouldn't be any different from  training without Pokerus?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: @Angzuril Don't effort values affect how many stat points a Pokemon gets when leveling up?

Comment: @Cyberson indirectly, yes. EVs are a part of the stat formula, so if a Pokemon has many EVs in one stat, that stat will also grow more. At the end of the day, though, every Pokemon has a limit of 510 total EVs, 252 in each individual stat (255 in some generations). Pokerus just makes it easier to gain those 510 points.

Comment: @scenia wouldn't that mean a Pokemon that gained pokerus early on in training would have higher stats than the same Pokemon if it had not gained pokerus?

Comment: Yes, the Pokemon with Pokerus will have the double of EVs then the "uninfected" one, and therefore higher stats. But the total EVs they can gain is the same.

Comment: I play VGC and nobody even cares if you hack your team in, just as long as everything's legal during the battles themselves.

Comment: @Cyberson only while none of them reaches the maximum. Since it only doubles the rate at which EVs are gained, but doesn't affect how many a Pokemon can have in total, it makes it a little easier to train it. It's a little like the Lucky Egg, which increases experience gained. This makes it faster to get a Pokemon to Level 100 (or 50 for competitive purposes), but it won't make a Pokemon go over Level 100. Since in championships, a Pokemon will always be fully EV trained, it makes no difference how quick it was to get there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Championships do not care about Pokérus. It is useful for training Pokémon, but having Pokérus does not have any effect in online battles.

Pokérus is used to raise [Effort Values](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values) (EVs) faster than normal. Note that it is not required for EV Training, but just cuts the amount of time required in half. From [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9rus) :

> When a Pokémon has the Pokérus, it gains double the effort values from battling.

However it does not increase the maximum EVs a Pokémon can obtain. This means you can fully EV train your Pokémon without ever having Pokérus. [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values#Fully_Trained_Pok.C3.A9mon):

> A Fully Trained Pokémon is a Pokémon that has reached 510 EVs overall, the maximum a Pokémon can achieve

It does not matter when a Pokemon gains EVs. Since Generation V, EVs are applied as soon as they are gained, and you do not need to level up in order for them to apply. The formulas for stat totals only care about the EV values, when they changed doesn't matter. [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Statistic#In_Generation_III_onward).

[image]

[image]

Lastly, although Pokerus may appear as a 'status' it does not prevent status conditions

> When a Pokémon is infected with Pokérus, their status screen will display an icon indicating this special "status" the same way status conditions would be noted. If the Pokémon becomes affected by a status condition such as Sleep, the Pokérus icon will be temporarily replaced until the status condition is cured.